# Why is using a variable to hold the results from a class method giving me this NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby, class, metaprogramming

I was trying this practice problem on assigning attributes to columns in a table (more specifically the self.finalize! method):

```
class SQLObject
  def self.columns
    return @columns if @columns
    results = DBConnection.execute2(<<-SQL).first
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        "#{table_name}"
      LIMIT 0
    SQL
    results.map!(&:to_sym)
    @columns = results
  end

  def self.finalize!
    # can use "columns" instead of "self.columns" b/c "columns" is a class method
    # defined on the class itself
    info = self.attributes
    self.columns.each do |column|
      define_method(column) { info[column] }

      define_method("#{column}=") do |val|
        info[column] = val
      end
    end

  def attributes
    @attributes ||= {}
  end
end
```

And I found that using "info" to store the results from the attributes instance method (which from what I understand, is only declared on this SQLObject class) gave me a NoMethodError that looked like this:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `attributes' for Cat:Class
```

Why does using "info" to store the call to the "attributes" method not work? And why is explicitly saying "self.attributes[column]..." in the "self.finalize!" method correct?

Comment: "And I found that using "info" ... gave me a NoMethodError" - No. Using `self.attributes` (or `attributes`) there gave you that error. `attributes` does not exist in that scope. It is an instance method. You're not currently in an instance method.

Comment: Ah wait, so are instance methods not accessible from class methods? I'm guessing that because I'm calling attributes from the "define_method" (which is an instance method) is why it works?

Comment: To call an instance method you need an instance.

Comment: Wait, so where is the instance of this class being used to call attributes? I thought that self refers to the class and not the instance of the class? I guess I'm still a bit confused on how it's being called on an instance when I put it inside of the each loop.

Comment: A better way to phrase my confusion, does putting "self.attributes" inside of that each loop make the "self" refer to an instance of my class? I was under the impression that self refers to the class itself.

Comment: "I was under the impression that self refers to the class itself." - no, not really. On that line it is the class, yes. But inside blocks you pass to `define_method`, it will be an instance of the class. When trying to grasp ruby's metaprogramming, the very first thing you need to master is "what is current `self` at this point?". Pretty much everything depends on this. May I recommend a book called "Metaprogramming Ruby"? It helped me a lot back in the day.